# Suppose that the matrix $M$ is invertible. Then the equation $Mv=0$ has exactly one solution, namely $v = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried doing this

> $M$ is invertible so $M^{-1}$ exists, therefore $(M^{-1})Mv = (M^{-1})0 = v = 0$

then I am confused on how to prove that this is the only solution.
Can I just say...

> Assume $M$ is not invertible, then its column vectors are not linearly independent, therefore for column vectors $\left\{v_1, v_2, \ldots , v_n\right\}$in $M$ and constants $\left\{c_1, c_2, \ldots , c_n\right\}$
>
> $$c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + \ldots + c_nv_n = 0$$ is a non-trivial solution to $Mv = 0$ because some ($c_kv_k$) term is not equal to zero?

sorry for the format

Comment: $M^{-1} (Mv) = (M^{-1} M) v = I v = v$. Hence if $Mv = 0$, then $(M^{-1} M) v = 0$ from which we **must** have $v=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much I see now from your answer that we must have v = 0.

Answer (score 1):

For your second part.

No. The condition is if $M$ is invertible. The moment you assume the case that $M$ is not invertible, it is irrelevant.

As for the first part. We started from the equation $Mv=0$ and we are interested to figure out what is $v$. Multiplying by $M^{-1}$ shows that $v$ has to be $0$, and hence it has a unique solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I upvoted you but my karma is too low for it to show up.